# Opposite of array merge in PHP

Tags: php

Ok, two arrays:

```
$first = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$second = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Is there a way (without looping through them if it can be helped) of doing an array_merge style function where it returns this array:

```
$new = array(6,7,8,9,10);
```

Where if it finds a match, it does not return it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff)

```
$new = array_diff($first, $second);
print_r($new);

/*
Array
(
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

[`array_diff()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) should do this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Answer (score 1):

its not an intersection, its a difference

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
array_diff ( $array1 , $array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for, in discrete terms, an intersection:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

**EDIT:** Whoops you want the opposite.

**EDIT 2:** Here you go, you want the difference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new = array_diff($first , $second );
```